# Entity Framework 4 doesn't support Curiously-Recurring Generic Pattern？

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

it seems if i use an custom class as base of an entity,the ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet will fail with stackoverflow exception

code is:

```
// This is generated by EF4 and i modify it to my custom class
public partial class EntityA : GClass<EntityA>
{
    ......
}

public partial class TestEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public ObjectSet<EntityA> EntityAs
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_EntityAs == null))
            {
                // here will throw stackoverflow exception
                _EntityAs = base.CreateObjectSet<EntityA>("EntityAs");
            }
            return _EntityAs;
        }
    }
    private ObjectSet<EntityA> _EntityAs;
}


// This is custom class
public partial class EntityA
{
}

// This is my custom base class
public class GClass<T> : EntityObject where T : class
{
    public virtual string GetStr()
    {
        return "GClass";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend creating an interface for your entity objects instead of changing the base class. Generated code should not be modified.

**Update:** Due to unexplained downvotes, I'm adding the code below, which spells out precisely what I mean:

```
// Generated by EF4
public partial class EntityA : EntityObject
{
    ...
}

// Interface defined in another file
public interface IGClass<T> where T : IGClass<T>
{
    string GetStr();
}

// Automatically generated by T4 template
public partial class EntityA : IGClass<EntityA>
{
    public virtual string GetStr()
    {
        return "GClass";
    }
}
```

The resulting code does use CRGP, but does so via an interface instead of a base class.

More info on T4 templates is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

Comment: the generated code could be modified via a code generator.
I need to put the common methods to the base class.

Comment: I still recommend creating an interface. The implementations can be generated into the partial class (in another file). Is there any reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: if use interface,i will need to implement things to every class,what i need is a base class to handle common process.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, a `T4` template would make it easy to implement all these functions in the derived classes.

Comment: yes,this should be one of the solutions,but i think it's a little hard to maintain,and less code-reuse.
another way is use POCO instead of inherit from EntityObject.

another thread i opened in MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c13a60cf-6121-47a4-b4f8-40cb8d6f109a